# Preventing iCloud out of space pop-ups on 128gb iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

Is it possible to prevent the iCloud out of space pop-ups from appearing on my iPhone?

It pops up every other time I use my phone. I have basically the default+$5 20GB iCloud plan,  but don't plan to upgrade.

I don't think it's a good usage of iCloud to backup all 128gb of my iPhone... (I'm actually about 90% capacity - obsessive video/photos)

Comment: Check into whats in your storage.  Settings > General > Storage & iCloud usage > Manage Storage.  For starters not "everything" backs up, music and Apps are good examples.  photo's and videos do but thru iCloud photo library not backups.  Also if you have ever upgraded phones, you need to manually delete the last backup from the old phone (it never goes away on its own).  and FWIW "default+$5 20GB iCloud plan" makes no sense, you either have free 5gb or the next level up is 50gb for 99cents a month.

Comment: My 64gb phone is basically 80% full, however the icloud backup is only 1.6gb

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn off the out of space message, instead you will need to manage your iCloud storage space.

To manage your storage first find out what is stored in iCloud. Settings > General > Storage & iCloud usage > Manage Storage.

Backup size to iCloud storage usage is not a 1:1 relationship as your question suggests, I.e. 128gb of iCloud storage is not needed to backup a 128gb phone.  Music and Apps are good examples of items not included in the backup.

Photo's and videos are stored in your iCloud space but as part of iCloud photo sharing, not a "backup".  As your question suggests this is the largest use of space on your phone, you might want to switch off iCloud photo sharing (settings > iCloud) to save the space.  Another good solution might be to switch this item off and download the Dropbox app, and let it backup photos and vids.

Another iCloud space waster might be old device backups.  A new device won't overwrite the old devices last backup.  When that backup is no longer needed it must be manually deleted.

"default+$5 20GB iCloud plan" makes no sense, you likely either have free 5gb plan or the next level up is 50gb for 99cents a month.  5gb should be plenty to backup your 128gb phone, if you turn off iCloud photo.  My 64gb phone is at about 52gb but my backup is just 1.6gb after compression and subtracting what's not backed up as part of a backup.

In summary, and to directly answer your question.  No you can't turn off the out of space errors, you must manage the use of iCloud space instead.